# regular expression matching a number of 7 digits all the same except the 4th one

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that checks the following :

a number with 7 digits having the following format : xxxyxxx

example : 1112111 -->match , 1111111 -->doesn't match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:
[`^(\d)\1{2}(?!\1)\d\1{3}$`](https://regex101.com/r/a8XadR/1)

That would capture the first digit from the beginning of the string `^` in a capturing group `(\d)\1{2}` and repeat that group 2 times. Then for the 4th one use a negative lookahead `(?!\1)` to check if that on is not the same.

Then match a digit and repeat the capturing group 3 times `\1{3}` until the end of the string `$`.

Comment: is there a way to do it without negative lookahead , as I'm trying to apply in oracle regexp_like.

Comment: @user123 I am not sure if that is possible without a lookahead. I have updated my answer so that it repeats the first capturing group 2 times and left and right digits should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible using backreferences:

```
(\d)\1\1[^\1]\1\1\1
```

Here `\1` refers to the first captured number, which should match all other seven numbers, except for the fourth one.

### Demo

I say "possible," because it depends on whether your tool/language supports backreferences.